# php wordpress - Subscribe to mailchimp and I can't see it in mailchimp interface

Tags: php, wordpress, mailchimp, subscribe

I want to subscribe a user to mailchimp list like that:

```
 require_once( get_template_directory().'/inc/Mailchimp.php');
     $listId='********';
     $merge_vars=array(
         'FNAME' => $name
    );
    $apiKey='***********************';
    $mailChimp=new Mailchimp($apiKey);

    $result=$mailChimp->lists->subscribe($listId, array('email'=>$email),
            $merge_vars,false,true,true,false);
```

And I get a result from mailchimp:

```
[email] => aa@s.co
[euid] => *****
[leid] => *****
```

It looks like it is working and really sign this user, but when I get in to mailchimp the list is empty!

I tried to wait few days and see maybe it will update, but no...

Someone know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 6th param (`$double_optin`) must be set to `false` if you want direct subscription.

When `true`, users receive a confirmation mail before and are added to the list once they've clicked the button in this mail.

MailChimp warns about this param : *`"Abusing this may cause your account to be suspended."`*. See here : https://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/2.0/lists/subscribe.php